# unable to get a do-while loop working inside an if-else statement using google appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, do-while

I'm trying to achieve the following:

1. Get appscript to recognise the latest csv file within a folder in google drive.
2. Once it does recognise it, it will import the file into google sheets.
3. If a file has been previously uploaded to the sheet, appscript should upload the new lines below the currently existing lines.
4. remove the headers (i.e Row 1) of any subsequent file uploaded after the first one.

The code I wrote keeps going in a loop and I can't seem to figure out to progress further.
I've tried a for loop inside a if-else statement but that terminates after the first iteration, hence attempting a do-while loop.

```
    function myFunction() {
  function importData()
  {
       function getLatestFileId(){

   var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Printer CSVs");
   var files = folder.next().getFiles();
   var lastFileId = files.next().getId();


   return lastFileId.toString();

}
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var id = getLatestFileId();
    var lastworkingrow = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getLastRow();
    console.log(typeof lastworkingrow);
    files = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(files.getBlob().getDataAsString());
    console.log(typeof csvData.length);
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var i=0;

   if (lastworkingrow < csvData.length) {
     var i=0;
        do {
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, (csvData[i].length)).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));  
    i++;
} while (i < (csvData.length));
    } else {
    var i=0;
    do {
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(files.getBlob().getDataAsString());
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, (csvData[i].length)).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));  
    i++;
} while (i < (lastworkingrow + csvData.length));
  }
  }
  importData();
}
```

Comment: getLatestField() get's referenced in the importdata function. The purpose of it is to find the latest file that has been uploaded into the google drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply do this.

```
function importData() {
  function getLatestFileId() {
    let folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Printer CSVs");
    let files = folder.next().getFiles();
    let lastFileId = files.next().getId();  // this will be the first
    return lastFileId;
  }
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let id = getLatestFileId();
  let files = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    
  let csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(files.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  console.log(typeof csvData.length);
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  if( sheet.getLastRow() > 0 ) csvData.shift(); // remove the header
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,csvData.length,csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

Comment: Much cleaner approach

Comment: Even if one can get away with intermixing indices I still prefer not to because it's easy to get lost and what the heck we've got a lot of letter to play with

Comment: Hi, I've just tried to do this have amended it slightly since I need the headers for the first upload only by doing the following:

 if(sheet.getLastRow < 0){
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,csvData.length,csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}else {
  csvData.shift(); // remove the header
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,csvData.length,csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
 but that doesn't seem to work. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: See my edit `if( sheet.getLastRow() > 0 ) csvData.shift(); // remove the header`